# How to remove VirtueMart Featured Products from category browsing page

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have used joomla and virtuemart to build a shopping cart in the following link [enter link description here](http://www.incube.com.hk/bbq/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=3&vmcchk=1&Itemid=3)

My problems are:

1. How to remove feature products in that category browsing page?
2. How to show feature products in a separate page in a separate menu item?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Featured products can be removed from your browse (category) page by commenting out the line

```
//echo $ps_product->featuredProducts(true,10,true);
```

in the following files (which file depends on which layout you're using)

```
/components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/browse/includes/

browse_layouttable.tpl.php
browse_listtable.tpl.php
browse_notables.tpl.php
```

2) I suggest making use of the VirtueMart Featured Products module (mod_virtuemart_featureprod) and [loading the module into an article](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just go to the VirtueMart component Products>Special products (which will show you a check on the products that are placed as "featured".Click on those products,go to their Product Status tab and just uncheck the box which says "On Special"